# Display Distribution List As A Column In Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

A client of ours suddenly wants to add a custom column to his Outlook contact list. He wants this column to display the distribution list that said contact is a part of.

Now at a glance this is much more complicated than he makes it out to be. Not every contact is necessarily in AD, and they could certainly be part of more than one list. This all has to be accounted for in the formula.

I'm leaning towards telling him this is beyond our scope of support, but I though I'd ask around first. Is there some pre-made code out there that performs a similar function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly retrieve that information programmatically (`ExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList`), but you cannot display that in the Contacts folder view.

```
for each lst in Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList
  Debug.Print lst.Name
next
```

Comment: In Javascript, I need to get the Name of the List (For example: if i have 5 groups where my email . I needt o get group name). I tried "ExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList.Name" but not returning.

Comment: var test = theMailItem.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfLists.count gives me how many groups, i need name of the group. Do you have any idea?@Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: GetMemberOfLists returns a list (AddressEntries object). Loop through that list.

Comment: Actually i looped through it... heMailItem.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfLists.count;  for(var i = 0; i < test; i++ ) { test.items.Name;} -> i used like this it throws me error.. will you just help to just get name of list

Comment: Because in js -> test.items.name or test.name not working completly. i want to get only list name not all members in the list

Comment: Soo what is the problem? Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfLists is the list of DLs, not the members of DLs. For the latter, you need to loop through AddressEntry.Members colleciton.

Comment: Actually i dont want the name of the Members. I jst need the name of the list. For Example: Team A with 16 members. I need only just a word "Team A" not 16 member names.

Comment: Yes. Don't loop over the AddressEntry.Members collection.

Comment: Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.?? -> if you know how to get only name of the list, please give a tip to solve. Thanks in advance

Comment: Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfLists it is not give me name of the List. It always says me undefined. So is there any way to get the name of the DL List.

Comment: Detail: I cannot get the Name of the list. For Example: Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList.Count -> it returns me 12. But i want the 12 Name of the lists. Please help me to find that. I am digging my head almost a day but still no results found.

Comment: I really do not understand the problem. Does the VB script in the updated answer above work for you?

Comment: No. I am doing this in Javascript. I am implementing for web app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260510/get-distribution-list-from-outlook-via-javascript

Comment: @ Dmitry Streblechenko: Do you have idea to solve my problem. I need help from you