# Get distribution list from Outlook via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, outlook

In Outlook, I have 7 Groups where my email id. I need to get the group names (only name of the group not members of the group) where my email id.
Group Names are: "Team A", "Team B" etc. Currently I can get group count.

```
var theMailItem = outLookApp.CreateItem(0);
//Count number of groups: which returns me 7
var test = theMailItem.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < test; i++) {
   alert(test[i].Name);
}
```

Above code always return null. I want only 7 groups names like "Team A", "Team B" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, all collections in OOM are 1 based, not 0.

Secondly, your "test" variable is an int, so `test[i]` makes no sense.

Thirdly, you can use a much simpler loop:

```
var dl = outLookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetMemberOfList();
for (var i = 1 ; i < dl.count; i++)
{
   alert(dl.Item(i + 1).Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Sorry to say still it returns me null. i tried above one earlier itself still no result. I really dont know because .count give me exact items but i cannot print the name. Is that problem with security?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Currently i can open outlook using activx. But it only works in IE. Is there any way to open IE from chrome (without installing any extensions) or open outllok from chrome? Thanks in adavnce

Comment: No, only IE can do COM

Comment: Also, if the reply answers your question, please mark it as such.